# Conditional deleting in sas

Tags: sas

I have a data set, which looks the following way:

```
1. individual  time  woman 
2.  1          2008    1
3.  1          2009    1
4.  1          2010    1
5.  2          2008    0
6.  2          2009    0
7.  2          2010    1
8   2          2010    0
9.  3          2008    0
10. 3          2009    0
11. 3          2010    0
```

The problem is that some of the **observations appear twice** in 2010 with both being a male and female. This is for instance the case with observation 7. and 8. I was wondering, if it is possible to delete an observation conditional on the past, i.e. for individual 2, it should delete observation 7, because 6 was 0.

I hope it makes sense,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should filter out all observations which have different value for `woman` than the first observation for given individual. Assumes data set is sorted by individual.

```
data x;
  set x;
  by individual;
  retain _woman;
  if first.individual then _woman = woman;
  else if _woman ^= woman then delete;
run;
```

Comment: The key here is the `delete` statement.  You can write any logic you need and use `delete` to remove any unwanted records.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do a similar statement, where I delete individuals, who does not have an observation in 2010 for instance?

Comment: Deleting single observations = `delete`.  You can't quite do the same thing for deleting whole sets of observations based on NOT having something, but it is possible in a slightly different way.  See my answer to your other question for an example of how to do it using the data step.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to keep the first observation for each `individual` and `time`?

You could do something like this (dataset should be sorted by `individual` and `time`):

```
data want;
set have;
by individual time;
if first.time = 1 then output;
run;
```